# SVG height with em is not responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, media-queries

I need make responsive `line-height` and `background-image` depends of `font-size` value:

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.93333333em;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='1.93333333em' width='400' viewBox='0 0 400 5' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMax' %3e%3cline x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0' style='stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:5' /%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hi people!<br>How are you?<br>I`m good!</p>
```

In this situation `1em = 30px`, so `1.933333em = 58px`. As you can see I set `height` of svg `background-image` too: `height='1.93333333em'`.
I expected that height of background will be `58px`, but actually it's `30px` like `1em = 16px`. If I set `height='58px'` for `background-image` I get what I want.

And if screen size is `500px`, that `line-height` changes, but `height` of `background-image` not.

How does `em` work in SVGs and how can I make SVG size responsive?

Comment: I guess em inside the SVG doesn't behave like em outside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

The SVG has no width or height but I defined the `viewBox='0 0 5 5'`. For the size you can use the CSS `background-size:1.93333333em;` and let the image repeat on x and y.

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding:0;
  line-height: 1.93333333em;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 5 5' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMax' %3e%3cline x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0' style='stroke:rgb(255,0,0);' /%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-size:1.93333333em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hi people!<br>How are you?<br>I`m good!<br><br></p>
```

Alternatively you can use CSS linear gradients instead of SVG for the background image.

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding:0;
  line-height: 1.93333333em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 1.93333333em, red 1.93333333em, transparent 2em, transparent 3.93333333em, red 3.93333333em, transparent 4em, transparent 5.93333333em ,red 5.93333333em, transparent 6em);

}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hi people!<br>How are you?<br>I`m good!<br><br></p>
```

Comment: thanks for answer! about secons solution: it's good, but I used this background only for simplicity of question code, in real code background-line is more complicate, so I can't use linear gradient. 

I think, I'll use your first solution, because I didn't find how `em` works inside `svg`, so I'll use it outside. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple gradient:

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.93333333em;
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      red 0,red 4px,
      transparent 4px,transparent 1.93333333em);
  padding-bottom:4px; /*to have a red line at the bottom also*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hi people!<br>How are you?<br>I`m good!</p>
```

Comment: thanks for answer! but I used this background only for simplicity of question code, in real code background-line is more complicate, so I can't use linear gradient.